# Value assignment using calloc

Tags: c, calloc, memset

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    int size = 5 ;
    int* c = (int*)calloc(size,sizeof(int));
    memset(c,0,size*sizeof(int));    // when I input 1 or another value it doesn't work
    
    for (int i=0; i<size;i++){
        printf("values %d\n", c[i]);
    }
       
    free(c);
}
```

This program's output in the below;

```
value 0
value 0
value 0
value 0
value 0
```

But if I change 0 value to 1:

```
value 16843009
value 16843009
value 16843009
value 16843009
value 16843009
```

I seperated the memory using calloc. I want to assign a value to this memory address that I have allocated with the memset function. When I give the value 0 here, the assignment is done successfully. I am displaying a random value instead of the values I gave outside of this value. How can I successfully perform this assignment using the memset function?

Comment: it always handy to have yor programmers calculator open, so that you can convert decimal into hex, all would have been revealed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `memset` function sets each **byte** in the given memory segment to the given value.  So you're not setting each `int` to 1, but each byte in each `int` to 1.

The decimal number 16843009 in hex is 0x01010101, which illustrates that this is exactly what happens.

If you want to set each `int` to a non-zero value, you'll need to do it in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

`memset` operates on bytes. It sets every byte to `1` rather than every 4-byte `int`. When you interpret the results as `int`s you get `0x01010101` in hex, which is `16843009` in decimal.